# firebase__webpack_imported_module_2__.auth.createuserwithemailandpassword is not a function.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following setup to connect to firebase but for some reason in the browser console it shows that auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() is not a function. Is there something wrong with my code? this is login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Login.css'
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "firebase/auth";


function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const signIn = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
//some fancy firebase
  }


  const register = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((auth) => {
          // it successfully created a new user with email and password
          if (auth) {
            navigate.push('/')
          }
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error.message))

    }

  return (
    <div className='login'>
            <Link to='/'>
                <img
                    className="login__logo"
                    src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Amazon_logo.svg/1024px-Amazon_logo.svg.png' alt=" "
                />
            </Link>
        <div className='login__container'>
          <h1>Sign-in</h1>

          <form>
            <h5>E-mail</h5>
            <input type='text' value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />

            <h5>Password</h5>
            <input type='password' value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />

            <button type='submit' onClick={signIn} className='login__signInButton'>Sign In</button>
          </form>

          <p>
            By signing-in you agree to the AMAZON FAKE CLONE Conditions of Use & Sale. Please
            see our Privacy Notice, our Cookies Notice and our Interest-Based Ads Notice.
          </p>

          <button onClick={register} className='login__registerButton'>Create your Amazon Account</button>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Also I will post my firebase.js here

```
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "Not mentioning my firbase config in and below",
  authDomain: "c",
  projected: " ",
  storageBucket: " ",
  messagingSenderId: " ",
  appId: " ",
  measurementId: " "
};

// const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

//const auth = getAuth(app);
//const auth = firebase.auth();
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

export { db, auth };
```

I removed auth. from auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => { console.log(cred); and now it is giving me the current error in console of browser as inspect:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot create property '_canInitEmulator' on string 'test1234@gmail.com
```

Tried all solutions that were previously here in stack overflow but none worked also read through some docs of new firebase v.9.0+ modules but nothing understood yet. I would appreciate some great help for this authorization of firebase with react js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:
Try it in your login.js

```
          import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
        
        const firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: "****************",
                authDomain: "************",
                projectId: "************",
                storageBucket: "*************",
                messagingSenderId: "***********",
                appId: "**************",
                measurementId: "******",
            };
    const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
    
    const register = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
            // for registration
            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((auth) => {
              console.log(auth)
              if (auth) {
                // if successfully created a new user with email and password
                // redirect the new user to the home page
                navigate('/')
              }
            }).catch(error => alert(error.message));
         }
```

Similar approach is applicable for signing in:

```
const signIn= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

   // for login 
   signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((auth) => {
    console.log(auth);
     if (auth) {
         // if successfully signed in, redirect the new user to the home page
      navigate('/');
    }
    }).catch(error => alert(error.message));

 };
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#createuserwithemailandpassword) is a top level function in the new Firebase [Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade). Try importing the function as shown below:

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"
import { auth } from "../firebase.js"; // update path 

const register = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // auth instance as first param
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((auth) => {
      // it successfully created a new user with email and password
      if (auth) {
        navigate.push('/')
      }
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error.message))
}
```

You must import `auth` instance that is `getAuth()` exported from Firebase file and not from `"firebase/auth"` SDK. The first param in `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` should be this auth instance but you only have `email` and `password` params right now.

Comment: what do you mean by importing auth instance ie getAuth() exported from firebase file.....I di not quite understand. I did import it from firebase.js . If I did not do then how should I import it? what to write instead of this (import { auth } from "firebase/auth";)?

Comment: @PrajeshMakootan you are exporting auth instance from here right `export { db, auth };` ? You should import that and use in `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`... currently you are importing auth from `import {auth} from "firebase/auth"` that's incorrect

Comment: thanks a lot now i understood what you meant

Comment: Can you explain me why is this better than using Web 8 "namespaced" `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` ?

I don't understand why do we switched from that to what I view as much more complex and confusing `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)`

Thanks for clarification ;x