# What is going on with new Google's Web 9 "Modular" syntax vs previous Web 8"Namespaced"

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

so I wanted to ask why is Google's new Web ver 9 "Modular" syntax better than Web 8 "Namespaced" syntax?

I think it brings a lot of confusion right now seeing all the stuff getting changed at least in my eyes right now - and I really can't grasp the idea behind this change.

I specifically refer to this question [firebase__webpack_imported_module_2__.auth.createuserwithemailandpassword is not a function.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71958148/firebase-webpack-imported-module-2-auth-createuserwithemailandpassword-is-not/71958207#comment130316631_71958207) , where in the comment section I ask specifically that.

Is the modularity really worth the fuss and also why is this syntax `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)` (I assume it involves dependency injection) better than previous `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`, and if so why? Thanks for answers ;x

Comment: The main goal of the new v9 API surface is to facilitate tree-shaking (removal of unused code) to make your web app as small and fast as possible. See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5eJQ3nPc6A

Comment: Okay, nice I wasn't really familiar with the tree-shaking thing, makes much more sense now - thank you for that video!

Comment: Glad I could clarify this point. I've written an answer along the same lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main goal of the new v9 API surface is to facilitate [tree-shaking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking) (removal of unused code) to make your web app as small and fast as possible.

You can also watch the following Firebase video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5eJQ3nPc6A